# How do I install Visual Studio Completely in D drive?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I need to install Visual Studio 2022 for Unity. I specified the installation location in my D drive
but C drive's space runs low. Thus, I could not install it. I don't know what components get installed. I've looked for many methods, and `mklink` caught my eye but not confident about it. If there was any other way to, I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 5):

No, unfortunately most of Visual Studio still gets installed on the main drive. Regarding to this [forum thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2017-installed-in-a-different-location/31005) 75% of VS gets installed on the main drive and just 25% on the chosen drive.
So you have no choice but to make space on your c drive.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I've got space occupied on my laptop after a previous Unity installation. I guess it will stay there unless I erase and re-install Windows.