Microsoft Visual Studio Community installation issue
I'm just starting to study C# and I was trying to install Visual Studio Community. But the installer forces me to use the disk (C:), and I don't have much space on that disk. Is there a way of not using that disk?
I tried reinstalling and changing the folders.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70878486/how-do-i-install-visual-studio-completely-in-d-drive

Does this answer your question? How do I install Visual Studio Completely in D drive?

When you install Visual Studio, you can select where you install Visual Studio in the Installation locations tab in the installer.
Under Visual Studio IDE you can click the three dots ... to be able to select which exact folder you want Visual Studio to be installed. From there just select a folder or the root directory of the drive you want Visual Studio to be installed in.

For more information about selecting where to install Visual Studio, see Select the installation locations in Visual Studio in the Visual Studio documentation.

Even if I choose the exact folder I want to install, 22.88 GB are still located on the disk (C:)

When selecting installation locations in Visual Studio, it's worth noting that

There are some tools and SDKs that have different rules on where they can be installed. Such tools and SDKs are installed on your system drive even if you choose another location.

For more details, please refer to the documentation.
The key to the solution involves adding the ability to set the paths for SDKs, which make up the bulk of the Visual Studio install size
(topping 100+GB for a complete installation). Many SDKs are not produced by Microsoft, so ensuring we are able set install paths for those external deliverables and ensure the entire product works correctly is taking time to complete.
The short-term workaround is to download large SDKs manually (before Visual Studio) and install them into your own, custom paths using each installer's UI. Visual Studio's installer can detect and use those pre-installed SDKs, and they will not be removed when you change selections in Visual Studio's installer.  In reference to the forum thread
